# Postgresql Regex - escape possessive quantifiers

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, regular-expression, regex

I have a query that is formed in Java

```
SELECT * from COMPONENTS WHERE name ~* = 'searchTerm';
```

This query hits PostgreSQL via JDBC and returns the results. I have to use `~*` because the user from the UI may search for the entries using a regex. (The user itself passes the regex from the UI and all security has been taken care of to prevent SQL-injection).

It all worked fine until the user searched for just `C++`. PostgreSQL returned with an error:

```
ERROR:  invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid
```

Upon reading many articles, I understood the
at `+` is acting like a possessive quantifier and that PostgreSQL doesn't support it. Is there a way I can escape such characters from the input string or is there a better way to move forward?

https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html

Comment: If your users are allowed to specify regexes, they should be expected to submit valid regexes themselves; you cannot escape anything for them because you can't know what they mean. Regular expression syntax is probably off-topic on this site anyway, though it's fully documented in the Postgres manual.

Comment: If you have to entertain regexp matches for some reason, but don't want *user input* to have any special meaning, you could escape all special characters from user input like demonstrated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45741630/939860.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't let the user enter regular expressions. A carefully crafted regular expression can hog the CPU forever.

If all you want to do is looking for substrings in a case insensitive fashion, use `ILIKE`:

```
WHERE name ILIKE '%C++%'
```

Comment: Well, it's a business requirement that we allow uses to do a wildcard search. The ```~*``` until I hit the snag and I'm not sure how to proceed further. Looks like ILIKE doesn't support the regex operations or does it?

Comment: No, it doesn't. if you need to support regular expressions, @mustaccio 's comment above is spot on: if your users are supposed to enter regular expressions, they will know enough to type `C\+\+` when looking for that string.

Comment: Hmm! The problem is some of the users might be unaware of what regex is and how to use it. So they'd simply input ```C++```

Comment: That's why I say you shouldn't let users enter regular expressions. This is not for tenderfeet. On the other hand, experienced users would hate you if you mess with their expressions. So give your higher ups the regular expressions they want, and tell them the blame will be on them.

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you for all the timely response.